# Unable to edit Route Tables for subnets (AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

after years of using this website to solve my problems, i have finally had to make an account to ask a question myself.

i am trying to deploy a publically accessible MySQL Database in AWS using RDS, but no matter how i configured it, i wasn't able to reach it from my own workstation. I revisited an AWS Academy Lab that covered RDS and configured it all the same, but the one in the Lab worked flawlessly. The DB instance's security group has an appropriate incoming MYSQL/Aurora Rule and the DB instance itself is set to be publically available.

Eventually i figured out what set the lab and my environment apart, the subnets that are automatically assigned to the Database i am trying to deploy are missing a gateway route, which i figure is the reason why i cannot communicate with it from my workstation at home, since the lab instance is accessible with the same security group and public availability configuration. "Simple!", i thought, until i tried to edit the tables only to find out that such a function is nowhere to be seen in my console.

as you can tell this is a newbie struggling to find the magic button, if you know how i can edit the routing tables for the subnets assigned to the DB instance (or if you think the problem lies elsewhere!), i would really appreciate it if you could point me in the right direction.

what i tried: i configured the DB instance to be publically available and configured an allow inbound MYSQL/Aurora rule from my home machine in the DB instance's security group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are asking how to edit route tables. See [Work with route tables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/WorkWithRouteTables.html).

Subnets and their route tables are part of VPC configuration. You use them in RDS (and other services) but they're part of VPC. Go to VPC, select Route tables from the left menu, then select the appropriate route table, and click Edit routes.

Comment: i looked deeper through that article and did find it eventually, thank you for your comment, the DB is operational and accessible now :)